# How to subscribe a function which has already subscribed in Angular5

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, observable, subscribe

I have a function basically OIDC security service which calls an API for fetching user details. I need this function at different places. I want to reuse this function and do some processing at 3 different places depending on conditions but since I cannot call subscribe on already subscribe function, Is there a way to achieve this without writing this piece of code again and again?

```
fetchUserDetails(){
            // If it is null call oidc service
            this.oidcSecurityService.getUserData().subscribe(
                (userData: any) => {
                    if (userData) {
                       return userData
                    } 
                });
           return null;
        }
```

If I directly call the function and do some processing, the error I get is userData is null.

Answer (score 1):

It largely depends on what you want to do but you can use `share()` (or maybe `shareReplay()`) before subscribing:

```
fetchUserDetails() {
    // If it is null call oidc service
    const obs$ = this.oidcSecurityService.getUserData().share();

    obs$.subscribe(
        (userData: any) => {
             if (userData) {
                 return userData
             } 
    });

    return obs$;
}
```